# Nginx proxy pass (not redirect)

Tags: nginx, drupal, proxy

I have a nginx server that runs drupal. We're changing the way our site runs. I want user.redangus.org to pull up the same page that is at redangus.org/user.

My nginx right now is resulting in a redirect to redangus.org/user, but I want the URL to stay as user.redangus.org

My nginx for this currently looks like:

```
# user.redangus.org
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name user.redangus.org;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/user$request_uri;
    proxy_set_header Host redangus.org;
  }
}
```

How do I get it to pull the page without redirecting to the page?

Comment: try adding `proxy_redirect off;`

Comment: No luck, still redirects to the site instead of just pulling it. Thanks for the suggestion!